# Filesystem unmounted after weekend

Tags: filesystems, mount, aix

I have a problem with an AIX server what I manage. I had some filesystem created to store the structure of an Oracle instance. But after the weekend scheduled reboot the filesystems are unmounted when we arrive on monday morning.

The unmounted filesystems appears in the /etc/filesystem file. There are two of the filesystems. Extracted from  /etc/filesystem file

```
/appli2/oracle/DATA/oradata05:
        dev             = /dev/lvoradata05HIST
        vfs             = jfs2
        log             = /dev/loglv01
        mount           = false
        account         = false

/appli2/oracle/DATA/oraarch:
        dev             = /dev/lvoraarchHISTO
        vfs             = jfs2
        log             = /dev/loglv01
        mount           = false
        account         = false
```

Any idea why the filesystem gets unmounted after weekend reboot?

We use AIX 6 as operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Your `/etc/filesystems`says for both filesystem `mount = false`.

So, edit your system `/etc/filesystems` to have:

```
/appli2/oracle/DATA/oradata05:
        dev             = /dev/lvoradata05HIST
        vfs             = jfs2
        log             = /dev/loglv01
        mount           = true
        account         = false

/appli2/oracle/DATA/oraarch:
        dev             = /dev/lvoraarchHISTO
        vfs             = jfs2
        log             = /dev/loglv01
        mount           = true
        account         = false
```

For more information:

- [*AIX* 6.x `/etc/filesystems` manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.files/doc/aixfiles/filesystems.htm)
- A [small AIX administration guide about filesystems](http://aix.itechcolumn.com/search/label/AIX%20Filesystem) (search for "mount a file system")

Comment: There is a command to modify this values or i need to use vi or other editor to modify the value ?

Comment: AIX way of doing things is through the smit tool (or its non-graphical equivalent smitty), but vi is fine with me. I added some info about AIX administration.

Comment: You could also use the chfs command.  `chfs -A yes /appli2/oracle/DATA/oradata05`